# Generate dynamic Image Graph from data using Php

Tags: php

I need help to create Dynamic image from data available in database ..
Like this..
https://files.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/1.png

can anyone suggest me idea  how to do this ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This library maybe help you [**pChart**](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)

**Example:**

[image: chart1][image]